# How to prove $\lim_{t \to +0} \int_{at}^{bt} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} dx=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$a, b \in \Bbb{R}, 0<a<b.$

For a continuous function $f: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$ the integral  $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} dx$ is convergent.

Then how can we show that

$$\lim_{t \to +0} \int_{at}^{bt} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} dx=0$$

Comment: Can you think of a substitution that makes it easier to handle?

Comment: I tried, but couldn't think of any substitution. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t > 0$, make the substitution $x = ty$. You obtain

$$\int_{ta}^{tb} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\,dx = \int_a^b \frac{f(ty)-f(0)}{y}\,dy.$$

The continuity of $f$ now makes it easy to conclude.